# Fail to load Image in Maven project

Tags: java, image, maven, url, classloader

I am working on an Java Maven project and trying to load an image from resource/Image folder using ClassLoader and it fails for some reason.
Everything was fine before I moved all the images from the "src/main/resource" to the "src/main/resource/Images" folder.
I must change the letter case of Images to something like "images" or "IMageS" to successfully load them, which is weird.

This is the code that I use to load image

```
Image i = null;
URL u = GameUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource(imagePath);
i = new Image(u.toString());
```

This is an path that I use, as an example
"Images/candy.png"

Error Message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()" because "u" is null

I expect that I can load the images using the exact path instead of paths that don't match the letter case of the actual folder

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `GameUtil` is. Maybe you can show your success case before moving folders, otherwise I can't judge why you failed.

So, I can only show my case;

```java
// comments: the resource location to resolve: either a "classpath:" pseudo URL, a "file:" URL, or a plain file path
org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(String resourceLocation);

@Autowired
org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader loader;
//  use like this(see source code comments):
//  Resource res = loader.getResource(String loaction);
//  URL url = res.getURL();
```

Comment: Hi, this is the success case:
URL u = GameUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("candy.png");
Image i = new Image(u.toString());

When move it to the src/main/resources/Images folder, I use the path below and it fails:
URL u = GameUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Images/candy.png");
Image i = new Image(u.toString());

When I change the path to images/candy.png it works fine.

Also I can load the image using 
Image i = new Image(GameUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/Images/candy.png"));
but when I substitute /Images/candy.png with Images/candy.png , it fails to load again.

Comment: Also I found that I can use the following code to load image using the correct path: "/Images/candy.png"
URL u = GameUtil.class.getResource("/Images/candy.png");

Comment: `class.getClassLoader().getResource("Images/candy.png");`  And  ` class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Images/candy.png");` is success on my local env.

Comment: I focus on getResource and classLoader#getResource source code. The func class#getResource include classLoader#getResource, and I saw a comment on the class#getResource func. ` If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. `  And  `Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
modified_package_name/name`  Else `Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').`